# парсинг простой структуры JSON

Tags: c#, json

Использую библиотеку NewTownSoft.
Столкнулся с проблемой парсинга простой JSON структуры:

```
[  
   {  
      "latitude":"1",
      "longitude":"2"
   },
   {  
      "latitude":"-3",
      "longitude":"5"
   }
]
```

Десериализуя через JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(); 
Необходимо указать класс в котором нужно описать структуру JSON. 
Как составить класс для вышеуказанного JSON?
Можно ли вообще это сделать не используя dynamic и т.п костылей? просто дефолтно.

Comment: В данном случае все элементарно. Создайте класс с двумя свойствами: `latitude` и `longitude` и тогда `DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>();`

Comment: А в чем проблема? Это обычный массив же. Воспользуйтесь инструментом: https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я использую библиотеку Newtownsoft  привык к ней.

Comment: @Bulson Может я что то неверно делаю. Я понял так:   создаю класс  class sat{ public string latitude{get;set;} public string longitude{get;set;}}  Потом  LIst<sat> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sat>>(json_text) , верно?

Comment: @icedev, этот инструмент как раз создает всю необходимую структуру классов для JSON.NET по вашему json: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9h7.png

Comment: Да. Вроде верно, а что не работает?

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, отличный инструмент. Класс составил верно, но вот парсит(в коде) он его почему то  очень геморно, 3 "лишних" функции создал.

Comment: @Bulson  улетает в Exception {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0."}

Comment: У вас похоже в json_text что-то лишнее попало

Comment: @АндрейNOP вроде все нормально,чекнул на валидность JSON

Comment: Нашел проблему,сам невнимательный, ох уж эти переменные с похожими названиями) json_text и json_test ))  Всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Visual Studio есть такой инструмент - Paste Special (Edit -> Paste Special), с помощю которого можно сгенерировать необходимые классы для парсинга JSON строки (Edit -> Paste Special -> Past JSON As Classes)։

```
public class Coordinate
{
    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

и использовать:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coordinate[]>(json_string);
```

**[Пример с DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nc0j4a)**